# Compile error after update Angular and RxJS 5 to 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I'm having an issue after updating libraries to new Angular 6 and RxJS 6.

I have `RouteService` class which is working as service. It uses `HttpClient` to get data from remote API. After update I'm getting some weird error when I try to compile project.

Here's my service class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Route {
    name:string;
    route_id:number;
    created_at:Date;
}

@Injectable()
export class RouteService {
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

    getRoutesList():Observable<Route[]> {
        return this.http.get<Route[]>(`http://localhost:8090/api/routes`)
        .pipe(catchError(ServiceUtil.handleError));
    }
}
```

Here's handleError method:

```
import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ErrorObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';

export module ServiceUtil {
    export function handleError(error:HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent)
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        else 
        console.error('An error occurred:', JSON.stringify(error.error));    
        return new ErrorObservable(error.error);
    }
}
```

After `ng serve` I'm getting error:

```
ERROR in src/app/service/route-service/route.service.ts(21,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{} | Route[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Route[]>'.
Type '{} | Route[]' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.

Failed to compile.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my code that causes error in new versions but was working in old one? Or something changed?

Comment: it's because of your `catchError`. I would catch errors inside a http interceptor and remove the code (which you now duplicate on every request) (see here on how to use interceptors https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8)

Comment: try to use `npm install --save rxjs-compat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used http interceptor as **@Riscie** suggested and it's working.

Here's part of my code:

```
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req:HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return <any>next.handle(req)
        .pipe(timeout(5000), tap(event => {}, error => {
            if(error == null)
                throw {"message": "Unknown server error", "code": 987};
            else if(error.error != null) {
                if(error.error.code != null)
                    throw error.error;
                else if(error.status != null)
                    throw "message": error.error.error, "code": error.status};          
            }
            else
                throw {"message": error+"", "code": 986}
        }));
    }
}
```

Is it correct now?

Answer (score 0):

As error says.

Change your method declaration to:

```
getRoutesList():Observable<Route[] | {}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere user of `getRoutesList` not expected `Route[]`.

```
getRoutesList(): Observable<any>
```

Or change your error `handlerError` return to

```
return Observable.throw(error.error)
```